# javac 9+ using Automatic-Module-Name from META-INF/MANIFEST.MF for module options

Tags: java, javac, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system

Is there any way for `javac` 9+ to use `Automatic-Module-Name` from a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` on the file system (not in a jar) for module options?

e.g., say `src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` contains:

```
Automatic-Module-Name: com.example.testmodule
```

and `src/main/java` does not contain a `module-info.java`.

Can I somehow get `javac` to accept, e.g., the following option?:

```
--add-reads com.example.testmodule=com.example.anothermodule
```

Assuming the jar containing `com.example.anothermodule` is on the module path.

What about using `Automatic-Module-Name` from a file-system (non-jar) `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` in `java` (instead of `javac`)?

Comment: Automatic modules are about using existing libraries, packaged in JAR files, as modules. There is no support at this time for automatic modules that are exploded on the file system. In any case, it sounds like are developing something and you'd like to give it a module name but you aren't ready to write a module-info.java yet. In that case you don't need --add-reads as automatic modules read all other resolved modules. Maybe you just need `--add-modules com.example.anothermodule` to ensure that it gets resolved (because no module explicitly requires it).

Comment: @AlanBateman I actually use `module-info.java`, I'm writing a Gradle plugin to support modules and wanted to ensure that I support all valid use cases.  Yeah, add reads doesn't make much sense there, I just wanted some example of using an `Automatic-Module-Name` on the command line, even if it isn't a very sensible example.  Thanks for the info.